# Unable to compile script for setting image active/inactive because of non-static member

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and I'm trying to make a script which when triggered will set an image active and then if triggered again will set it inactive.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class PopImage : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject PopImg;
    static void Main() {
    if (PopImg.activeSelf) {
        PopImg.SetActive(false);
    }
    else {
        PopImg.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

`PopImage` is the script name, `PopImg` is the image name that needs to be activated/deactivated.

I receive the following errors.

> Assets/PopImage.cs(10,6): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `PopImage.PopImg'
>
> Assets/PopImage.cs(11,5): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `PopImage.PopImg'
>
> Assets/PopImage.cs(14,5): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `PopImage.PopImg'

Comment: well your `Main` method is `static` and the `PopImg` value is non-static -> the static method Main can not access it. Note that in Unities `MonoBehaviour` there is no such thing as `public static Main` usually. You rather want to use `private void Awake()` or `private void Start()` instead

Comment: @derHugo I edited the script, can you please provide new feedback?

Comment: Wow wait now you changed the entire script ... please avoid doing that and rather close the question and open a new one

Comment: @derHugo Will keep in mind. Can you please help me with the current one?

Comment: well, it compiles now ...

Comment: @derHugo It compiles but how do I pass the information about which gameobject I am talking about?

Answer (score 0):

## Edit

Your edited code should now be compiling. You should not be getting any more errors with this file.

---

## Original

You will want to take a look at Unity's [MonoBehaviour](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) class and its lifecycle and methods. You do not use `static void Main()` as an entry point into the script.

Comment: @GiorgiQutateladze are you still getting compile errors with your edited code?

Comment: It compiles but how do I pass the information about which gameobject I am talking about?

Comment: The same way you would pass along any other value: through class variables.